# Lowercase J Tail Cut Off

Tags: html

For some reason, when I put a lowercase J character inside a `span`, it cuts off the tail. You can easily see this by changing the font color on hover. I tested this in Chrome 32 on OSX and Safari 7.0.1.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <span>j</span>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-size:30em;
    text-align:center;
}
span:hover {
    color:red;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bRs3Q/2/

Why does this happen, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: What browser? Looks fine under Chrome 32 and Firefox 26 on Windows.

Comment: I tried it in Chrome 32 on Mac and Safari 7.0.1.

Comment: You should include relevant HTML and CSS in the question itself (a jsfiddle is a nice extra, but not sufficient) and identify the browser(s) tested, in the question itself.

Comment: I see also a strange behavior in the Android 4.3 browser. The letter is only partially recolored, but when I move the viewpoint it looks like expected.

Comment: Specifying a `line-height` (even 0) on `span:hover` will fix this; or `display: block` on the `span`; or using a `p` or `div` tag instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because a span is an inline element; why it only does it on `:hover`, I do not know. I couldn't find anything with a quick search, so I can only guess that maybe that part of the text lies outside the `span` and `:hover` doesn't expand outside the element.

You can do a few things to fix this:

1. use a block-level element, like `p` or `div`
2. set the `span` to `display: block`
3. set a `line-height` on the `span:hover` (even 0) will fix the issue

Comment: I can't use a block-level element, but the `line-height` trick works fine. It breaks with a transition, though: http://jsfiddle.net/bRs3Q/4/. Any ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bRs3Q/6/: you can add `padding` (`20px` works here but will likely be based on the font you are using and how the characters are rendered). I've added a background-color to show what happens with a span containing text, which supports my theory above. The padding is commented out for this purpose also.